# JQuery Selector inside created element

Tags: javascript, jquery

i like to select all div's that's a self created element contains.

```
var element = $("<div></div><div></div>");
var length = element.select("> div").length; // should return 2
```

Comment: It is returning 2, http://jsfiddle.net/d3athR0n/HvzDe/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code works fine (i.e. it returns two), for example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ByR9Q/1/

Alternatively, you can just use `element.length`:

```
var element = $("<div></div><div></div>"),
    the_length = element.length;
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ByR9Q/)